# How to set CurrencySymbol on Readonly CultureInfo.NumberFormat?

Tags: .net, cultureinfo, number-formatting

I'm trying to format a currency (Swiss Frank -- de-CH) with a symbol (CHF) that is different that what the default .Net culture is (SFr.). The problem is that the NumberFormat for the culture is ReadOnly.

Is there a simple way to solve this problem using CultureInfo and NumberFormat? Is there some way I can override the CurrencySymbol?

Example:

```
Dim newCInfo As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(2055)
newCInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "CHF"
MyCurrencyText.Text = x.ToString("c",newCInfo)
```

This will error on setting the `NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` because `NumberFormat` is `**ReadOnly**`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call `Clone` on the `CultureInfo`, which will create a mutable version, then set the currency symbol.

You could be more specific: fetch the `NumberFormatInfo` and only clone that. It's slightly more elegant, IMO, unless you need to change anything else in the culture.

Example in C#:

```
using System;

using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CultureInfo original = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(2055);
        NumberFormatInfo mutableNfi = (NumberFormatInfo) original.NumberFormat.Clone();
        mutableNfi.CurrencySymbol = "X";
        Console.WriteLine(50.ToString("C", mutableNfi));
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, and simply simple. I could kick myself for missing this. Thanks!