# Get Latest Turkish Currency symbol

Tags: c#, culture

Currently I am getting fold turkish symbol as I need to display (838,72 TL).

I am using ("tr-TR") as specificculture to get currency symbol.

Please help me how can I get TL as currencysymbol for this culture?

```
stringBuilder.Append("<td class=\"price\">" + Environment.NewLine);

// No just use the value we have
// nnn,nn TL
stringBuilder.Append(FormatPrice(model.Country.SpecificCulture, retailerProduct.Price));
stringBuilder.Append("</td>" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: How would we know what you did or need to do without any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to set CurrencySymbol on Readonly CultureInfo.NumberFormat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951689/how-to-set-currencysymbol-on-readonly-cultureinfo-numberformat)

Based on John Skeet post I did the below and it worked. 
 Thanks all for your help.

```
                case "tr-TR":
                    var original = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");
                    var mutableNfi = (NumberFormatInfo)original.NumberFormat.Clone();
                    mutableNfi.CurrencySymbol = "TL";
                    double price = Convert.ToDouble(retailerProduct.Price);
                    stringBuilder.Append(price.ToString("C", mutableNfi));
                    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Workig example below:

```
var ri = new RegionInfo("tr-TR");
Console.WriteLine(ri.CurrencySymbol);
```

Comment: It is coming as TR, I want TL (turkish Lira)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly but CurrencySymbol for "tr-TR" equals to "TL" which is what you are looking for. Am I right?

Comment: Yes I am and I am trying instead of hard coding is there a way of getting TL symbol.

Comment: Hmmm this quest led me to this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/03/18/9976688.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use Property `RegionInfo.CurrencySymbol`:

```
var regionInfo = new System.Globalization.RegionInfo("tr-TR");
var currencySymbol = regionInfo.CurrencySymbol;
```

Comment: No I am not getting TurkishLira(TL) symbol.